# Can the rolling sequence problem of hot-rolled steel slab be solved by the tsp model in Optaplanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner, planning

In the hot rolling process of the iron and steel industry, there is a problem of sorting rolled slabs. Because adjacent slabs have a limit of jumping value, the slabs must be rolled in a certain order during the rolling process to ensure smoothness.

The preparation of the rolling unit plan (slab ordering) is academically solved using the tsp model. I would like to ask if the tsp model can also be imitated in Optaplanner to solve my problem?

My idea is:
The slab to be selected-Visit (`PlanningEntity`), the first slab-Domicile, the size jump value between adjacent slabs (such as width jump, thickness jump, etc.)-distance; Measurement = Location...

I also use the time chain model to design. I don’t know if my idea is feasible. Please help me answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're basically using the "chained through time design pattern" (see docs, chapter design patterns), which is the same pattern that TSP and VRP use, but also the task assignment example. I recommend looking at the task assignment example, and using a shadow variable to calculate the starting time of each slab, taking into account the overhead time cost of switching from the previous kind of slab to the next one (ideally none).

See [our videos on domain modeling and design patterns and shadow variables](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns).

Comment: So excited to receive your reply!
I am very happy that my idea has been approved by you. I now know that I can refer to the tsp model.
So if I want to use Optaplanner to evaluate the existing rolling plan to determine whether the existing plan is reasonable , is this also feasible? (That is to say, I had a solution at the beginning) Is it the same as the traditional usage in terms of modeling?